# Structuring Angular 4 Application with Login pages and other standard Dashboard pages

Tags: angular

I am building a small web application that contains a login page and other dashboard pages.

I have adopted the following structure:

```
- app
    - main
       - dashboard pages
    - shared components
       - navbar components
    - application pages (e.g. app.module.ts)
```

Using `router-outlet`, on the `app.component.html` page, I am able to load all the pages, as demonstrated below:
[image]

However, I am trying to use different `router-oulet`s to only show the login page without the frame as shown here:
[image]

I am new to Angular and trying to put a router-outlet inside another outlet it did not work. Any design thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It did not work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: On loading `http://localhost/app/signin` I'd want to only see the login page without the sidebar and header frames and on accessing  `http://localhost/app/dashboard`, It should display the dashboard as on image one. @georgeawg

Comment: dont't put the sidebar outside the `router-oultet`, you can create a component with the sidebar to use inside the `router-oultet` for all your pages (except the login) and a different component without the sidebar for the login page.

Comment: @FabioG thank you, let me try that.